# What dB level corosponds to the lower 8 bits of a 24 bit pcm/wav file?

Tags: recording, tone, test

I'm wondering, what is the maximum peak amplitude, in decibels, that will register in the first 8 bits of a 24 bit wav and leave the upper 16 as 0's?
Would something like -99.85dB be low enough or would it have to be below -100dB (typical software volume controllers)

Answer (score 2):

PCM samples in a *wav* file are coded in 2's complement.

For a N bits sample size, it means that the maximum positive sample value is `2^(N-1) - 1` and the minimum negative value is `-2^(N-1)`.

For N = 24, it leads to a maximum positive value of `2^23 - 1`.
The maximum positive value of a sample composed of 8 lower bits set to 1 is `2^8 - 1`.

So the dB FS value of such an 8 bit sample would be `20 * log10((2^8 - 1) / (2^23 - 1))`, that is approximately `-90.3 dB FS`.

If you are measuring level with an RMS meter and your signal is a sinusoidal tone, the RMS meter should display about 3 dB less.

(Using `2^23`instead of `2^23 - 1` as denominator has a negligible effect on the numerical result, although it is an interesting question to decide which one should be used).